# line up security identifier numbers horizontally

Tags: text-formatting

I have these security identifiers IDs (SIDs)

```
SID_1
S-1-2-12-347289564783285475
SID_2
S-1-2-12-312478290434839212
S-1-2-12-312748912347723432
S-1-2-12-123475184123489632
SID_3
SID_4
S-1-2-12-384721849326143123
S-1-2-12-324624783246712332
SID_5
SID_6
```

and I need to line them up horizontally so I can feed them to an algorithm which only accept the IDs in this form:

```
SID_1:S-1-2-12-347289564783285475
SID_2:S-1-2-12-312478290434839212:S-1-2-12-312748912347723432:S-1-2-12-123475184123489632
SID_3
SID_4:S-1-2-12-384721849326143123:S-1-2-12-324624783246712332
SID_5
SID_6
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

with `awk` :

```
awk '/^S-/{s=s":"$1;next}s{print s}{s=$0}END{print s}' file

SID_1:S-1-2-12-347289564783285475
SID_2:S-1-2-12-312478290434839212:S-1-2-12-312748912347723432:S-1-2-12-123475184123489632
SID_3
SID_4:S-1-2-12-384721849326143123:S-1-2-12-324624783246712332
SID_5
SID_6
```

Answer (score 0):

using `sed`

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\nS-/:S-/g' file
SID_1:S-1-2-12-347289564783285475
SID_2:S-1-2-12-312478290434839212:S-1-2-12-312748912347723432:S-1-2-12-123475184123489632
SID_3
SID_4:S-1-2-12-384721849326143123:S-1-2-12-324624783246712332
SID_5
SID_6
```